# A local variable `person' cannot be used before it is declared

Tags: c#, variables, local

i am making this school excercise where I have to fill in empty gaps to complete the code.
This is what I have:

```
using System;

class Program {
  public static void Main() {
    var person;
    person = Tuple.Create("John", "Doe");
    string s = "Hello, "+person.Item1 + ", " + person.Item2;
  }
}
```

When I run it I get the following error:
Error in source program:

> (5,5): error CS0818: An implicitly typed local variable declarator must include an initializer
>   (6,5): error CS0841: A local variable 'person' cannot be used before it is declared
>   (7,26): error CS0841: A local variable 'person' cannot be used before it is declared

Here are the empty gaps that I am allowed to edit.

```
 using System;

 class Program {   public static void Main() {
     ______ person;
     person = ________________________________
     _______ s = "Hello, "+person._____ + ", " + person.______;   } }
```

Comment: Here's a hint for first error. if you use var Person; compiler does not know what type it resolves to unless for example, it is initialized to var Person = 0; where the compiler knows var is int. You may replace "var" with the data type you initialized in the next line.

Comment: Isn't the error msg clear? You write `var person;` __before__ you give the compiler a chance to deduce the type. Put the declaration and the intialization into one line and it will work: `var  person = Tuple.Create("John", "Doe");`

Comment: Thank you both. It worked when I wrote Tuple<string, string> person;

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully the errors the compiler is giving you:

> (5,5): error CS0818: An implicitly typed local variable declarator must include an initializer

Ok, so it's saying that if you use an implicitly typed local variable, you need to initialize it. The reason is that if you don't initialize it, how is the compiler going to figure out the type?

This is fine:

```
var s = "Hello"; //this works because the compiler can figure out s is 
                 //a string because you are initializing it with the
                 //string "Hello".
```

But this isn't:

```
var s; //this fails because the compiler doesn't know what type s is.
s = "Hello";
```

Now, you can avoid this not using implicitly typed variables to begin with; simply use explicitly typed variables. This works perfectly fine:

```
string s; //the compiler doesn't have to figure out anything, 
          //s is a string, period.
s = "Hello";
```

Ok, so now we know that the compiler can't figure out what `person` is. Once thats clear you have to understand that the declaration of `person` has failed and therefore the compiler will ignore it altogether, *but* it will keep on trying to make sense of the rest of your code as much as it can.

So, once its clear that the variable `person` doesn't exist as far as the compiler is concerned, the next two errors make perfect sense:

> (6,5): error CS0841: A local variable 'person' cannot be used before it is declared 
>   (7,26): error CS0841: A local variable 'person' cannot be used before it is declared

The compiler is simply telling you that you are trying to use a variable named `person` that has never been declared. Once when you try to initialize it: `person = Tuple.Create("John", "Doe");`, and once when you try to access it: `string s = "Hello, " + person.Item1 + ", " + person.Item2;`

Fix the declaration, and everything will work.

Comment: My error was different but the part where you say _"Read carefully the errors the compiler is giving you"_ saved me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error mentioned there is actually about the [implicit type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) declaration rules.
When declaring a variable using `var` you should always have something in the right side, 
like:

```cs
var i = 10; // var is internally converting to `int` by Compiler
```

because Compiler is determining `var` type from the right side operation and in this case, it will be the same as:

```cs
int i = 10;
```

So particularly for your case in order to make the code compilation successful combine lines `5` and `6`, like this:

```cs
var person = Tuple.Create("John", "Doe");
string s = "Hello, " + person.Item1 + ", " + person.Item2;
```

Comment: That won't comply with the excercise. He's not supposed to use implicitly typed variables.